# WinForms: Could not load System.Memory

Tags: winforms, npgsql, sqlconnection

I do refactoring legacy WinForms app.
Now it is NET Framework 4.8 based app working with SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

But during the execution this code:

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();
connect.ConnectionString = connectionString; // <-- here error happens
```

I receive the error:

> ------------ System.IO.FileLoadException   HResult=0x80131040   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory,
> Version=4.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or
> one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
> does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80131040)   Source=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient   StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.Data.LocalDBAPI.GetLocalDbInstanceNameFromServerName(String
> serverName)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
> connectionString)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
> connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
> key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
> userConnectionOptions)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
> key)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
> value)
>
> Inner Exception 1: FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

It occurs after I have added Npgsql 7.0.4 Nuget package.

How to fix it?

The simplified code:

```
//Installed Nuget System.Memory (fresh dll: 4.5.5.0)
// using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

and the message:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Memory, Version=4.5.5.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

Comment: did you install - https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory

Comment: No, will install now.

Comment: After installation the Nuget System.Memory the exception message little bit changed:  now it is about 4.0.1.1. only: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)